# Autocompletion in c# DevExpress TextEdit

Tags: c#, autocomplete, devexpress, textedit

I am using devexpress TextEdit in c#.net application and i want to implement auto completion for TextEdit.My doubt is that for normal TextBox we set `AutoCompletion mode property`.But in devexpress TextEdit how we can ?

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify for what you need autocomplete, but I think you have to use [MRUEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/MruEdit.xml) instead of TextBox.

Comment: jmservera: ok agree.But how can i implement autocomplete ??

Comment: You don't need to implement anything, just drop the MRUEdit (http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsMRUEdittopic)

Comment: MruEdit is a ComboBox which allows you to edit its dropdown items collection by writing a new value.  For more information, please refer to our documentation: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsMRUEdittopic

Answer (score 5):

In fact you can easily do it :

```
var tx = TextEditMoveTo.MaskBox;

AutoCompleteStringCollection customSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
customSource.Add("Yes");
customSource.Add("You");
customSource.Add("Can");

tx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
tx.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
tx.AutoCompleteCustomSource = customSource;
```

And it works like a charm :)

You can read more about it [here](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/81601/280039.aspx).

Credits goes to [Uwe Keim](http://www.codesnipp.it/html/add-autocomplete-for-devexpress-textedit-and-comboboxedit)